Encoding ac and dc cofficients in jpeg compression after zigzag ordering
I'm trying to implement JPEG compression in python and so far I have done the following steps

Color Space conversion
Downscaling chrominance channels
8x8 block splitting ( adds padding if size is not perfect )
DCT
Quantization
ZigZag Ordering
runlength encoding on ac coefficients, transformed into (RUNLENGTH, SIZE)(AMPLITUDE) pattern

e.g [(0, 2), -2, (4, 1), 1, (0, 0)]

DPCM on dc cofficients

I'm a lil confused about 2 things.
how should I encode the dc coefficients before Huffman encoding. Is there a specific pattern just like ac coefficients?
After encoding dc coefficients are stored in their respective blocks ?
[dc],[ac_value],....
or all dc values are stored separately and Huffman encoded separately
[dc value,...]
[ac values,...]
I read that fixed huffman tables are used by most encoders. Where exactly can I find the fixed standard huffman tables.
I'm not sure if I am missing any crucial steps so far?

Are you saying you have not looked at the source code for the MANY MANY existing JPEG encoders?

I have reviewed several open-source JPEG encoders in Python. However, many of them deviate from the official JPEG standards, some of them omitting crucial steps which leads to confusion. I'm trying to understand and implement a fully compliant JPEG encoder.

Many parts of the JPEG standard are optional.  The differenced DC components are read in zigzag order, and Huffman encoded.  Then the AC components are read in zigzag order and Huffman encoded  They do not alternate.

There is easy to read JPEG source code (C++ and Delphi) at http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/index.html and a book that goes along with it https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_1
